# Undefined local variable or method with respond_with (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have problem with matcher respond_with. My error (500 Internar server error) is undefined local variable or method `orders'. This is my method in **OrdersController**:

```
respond_to :json, :html
       ...
  def create
    order = meal.create_order(order_params)
    respond_with orders
  end
```

My **routes:**

```
resources :orders, only: [:index, :create, :destroy], defaults: {format: :json} do
  member do
    put '/delivered' => 'orders#delivered'
  end
end
```

What is wrong with that code?

Comment: Might just be me but I don't think that there is enough info here. Also what is the `orders` in the `respond_with orders`? Is that created somewhere else? Please provide some more of the controller code.

Comment: I think orders is a name of resource in routes. When I change orders for example to Order.all I have similiar problem undefined method `to_model'.

Comment: Looks like you found a solution, excellent! That is interesting about the `Order.all`. I would need to see the models for meal and order to dig a bit deeper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing an `s` or perhaps there shouldn't be one.

```
order = meal.create_order(order_params)
respond_with order
```